# Google sign-in from Firebase Unity Desktop app

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am developing a PC app with Unity. Since I want to use Google sign-in, Firebase seems to provide a nice layer of abstraction. However, I can only find documentations for Unity iOS and Android apps, not for *PC* app. Is this supported?

I’ve also found https://github.com/googlesamples/google-signin-unity, which seems to provide most of what I want, but is this a recommended way?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like I found what you were looking for (probably ), it was enough to rummage through the FireBase documentation
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/start?authuser=0

**Register new users**

```
auth.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password).ContinueWith(task => {
  if (task.IsCanceled) {
    Debug.LogError("CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync was canceled.");
    return;
  }
  if (task.IsFaulted) {
    Debug.LogError("CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
    return;
  }

  // Firebase user has been created.
  Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
  Debug.LogFormat("Firebase user created successfully: {0} ({1})",
      newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);
});
```

**Log in existing users**

```
auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password).ContinueWith(task => {
  if (task.IsCanceled) {
    Debug.LogError("SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync was canceled.");
    return;
  }
  if (task.IsFaulted) {
    Debug.LogError("SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
    return;
  }

  Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
  Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})",
      newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);
});
```

**Install the authentication state change event handler and get the user data**

```
void InitializeFirebase() {
  auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
  auth.StateChanged += AuthStateChanged;
  AuthStateChanged(this, null);
}

void AuthStateChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs eventArgs) {
  if (auth.CurrentUser != user) {
    bool signedIn = user != auth.CurrentUser && auth.CurrentUser != null;
    if (!signedIn && user != null) {
      DebugLog("Signed out " + user.UserId);
    }
    user = auth.CurrentUser;
    if (signedIn) {
      DebugLog("Signed in " + user.UserId);
      displayName = user.DisplayName ?? "";
      emailAddress = user.Email ?? "";
      photoUrl = user.PhotoUrl ?? "";
    }
  }
}
```

**THE ANSWER IS PROBABLY HERE (Authentication by logging in to Google and Unity)**

1. Register your Unity project and configure it to use Firebase.(https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/namespace/firebase/auth?authuser=0)
2. If your Unity project already uses Firebase, it means that it is already registered and configured for Firebase.
3. if you don't have a Unity project, you can download a sample application .
   (https://github.com/google/mechahamster)
4. Add the Firebase Unity SDK (specifically, Fire base Auth. unitypackage) to your Unity project.
   (https://firebase.google.com/download/unity?authuser=0)
5. Подробные инструкции по выполнению этих задач начальной настройки см. В разделе Добавление Firebase в проект Unity .
   (https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup?authuser=0#prerequisites )
   https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/google-signin?authuser=0

P.s "I didn't find anything else sorry"

Comment: Thanks for the comment - but that’s signing in users with username/email, not the federated login I’m looking for. Also, I am trying to see if firebase works with unity desktop apps...